# ASP.NET CalendarExtender cannot get the month?

Tags: asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This is the code in GridView template : Everything works well except the calendar cannot display the month: Example :18/08/2015 . It only display : 18/00/2015.

```
<FooterTemplate> 
                                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewLeaveDate" runat="server"   CssClass="textnumber"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hplNewGetCalendar" 
                                                                NavigateUrl="javascript:void(null)" 
                                                                runat="server">
                                                                <img id="imgNewLeaveDate" alt="" src="/App_Themes/Admin/img/calendar.png" runat="server" />
                                                        </asp:HyperLink>
                                                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calNewLeaveDate"
                                                                Format="dd/mm/yyyy"
                                                                Animated="false"
                                                                PopupButtonID="hplNewGetCalendar"
                                                                TargetControlID="txtNewLeaveDate"
                                                                runat="server" />
                                                        <asp:MaskedEditExtender
                                                                ID="meeNewLeaveDate"
                                                                TargetControlID="txtNewLeaveDate" 
                                                                Mask="99/99/9999"
                                                                MessageValidatorTip="true" 
                                                                OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
                                                                OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
                                                                MaskType="Date"
                                                                Century="2000"
                                                                CultureName="en-GB"
                                                                UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear"
                                                                InputDirection="LeftToRight"
                                                                runat="server"/>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtNewLeaveDate"
                                                               runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewLeaveDate"
                                                                ErrorMessage="Required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
</FooterTemplate>
```

And the result:
[image]

What is the probem, I'm using VS 2010 !
And in the Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <globalization
           fileEncoding="utf-8"
           requestEncoding="utf-8"
           responseEncoding="utf-8"
           culture="en-GB"

        />
.........................
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG! Just edit something, and it works like a charm:

```
<FooterTemplate> 
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewLeaveDate" runat="server"   CssClass="textnumber"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hplNewGetCalendar" 
                                                                NavigateUrl="javascript:void(null)" 
                                                                runat="server">
                                                                <img id="imgNewLeaveDate" alt="" src="/App_Themes/Admin/img/calendar.png" runat="server" />
                                                        </asp:HyperLink>
                                                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calNewLeaveDate"
                                                                Format="dd/MM/yyyy"  Animated="false" 
                                                                PopupButtonID="hplNewGetCalendar"  TargetControlID="txtNewLeaveDate" runat="server" />
                                                        <asp:MaskedEditExtender
                                                                ID="meeNewLeaveDate"
                                                                TargetControlID="txtNewLeaveDate"  Mask="99/99/9999" 
                                                                MessageValidatorTip="true" 
                                                                OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
                                                                OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
                                                                MaskType="Date"
                                                                ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"
                                                                CultureName="vi-VN"
                                                                UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear"
                                                                runat="server"/>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtNewLeaveDate"
                                                               runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewLeaveDate"
                                                                ErrorMessage="Required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
</FooterTemplate>
```

And the Web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

[image]